# Azure resource Created By & Timestamp

Tags: azure, event-tracking, azure-resource-group

We have Azure environment with 3 different subscription and around 5 project resources are deployed in this environment.

Each project team has rights to create resources under specific Resource Group (RG) within Azure.

Now from Azure Admin perspective, i would like to know Who, When

This is basic requirements for any organization to track their cost, resource information. When i looked in Azure, this information is not available directly at resource level.

Few posts are mentioning to use Tagging for this or use logs (2 years back, really?)? Is it? I am surprised.

Can i use Application Insight for this? or only available for App Service kind of services?

Please help me to get this information in efficient way

Comment: Go to ResourceGroup-> Deployments . Click on any deployment and you will get all details .

Comment: this doesnt really work, say anything created with powershell\sdk\rest calls\terraform would leave no trace @GauravMoolani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is to implement some sort of logging (like poll Azure Subscription events) and save it somewhere. You can use Azure Monitor to achieve that rather easily. But by itself Azure doesnt offer anything like that out of the box.

you can use tagging, but with obvious challenges. logs only go 3 months back.

Comment: Thanks 4C for your response

Really? Basic info which has direct impact on Cost needs to get this way?

I also check with one of guy with AWS, they are also talking about logs and so on

There may be some reason for Cloud provider to do in this way, so i am interested to know the reason which is out of my knowledge

Comment: well, I cant tell you that, I'm not the person who designed this, but thats the only way to do it currently. tags and\or logs

Comment: @ManishJoisar just to give reference here is the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-using-tags#tags-and-billing